# What API do I call to measure popularity growth for specific tags over time?

Tags: support, discussion, api, tags

I believe I can use the Stack Exchange API to get total questions that fit chosen tags.

I have an example I wrote myself here:
          [data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/767064/number-of-posts-for-excel-and-python](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/767064/number-of-posts-for-excel-and-python)

How do I measure the growth of popularity of a particular tag or a particular bunch of tags over time using the Stack Exchange API?

E.g.

- [excel] vs [python]
- [excel]+[python] vs [excel]+[php]

and so on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you mean something like [**this plot**](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/201360?ShowScore=0&Tag1=excel&Tag2=python&Tag3=NA&Tag4=NA#graph)? :

[image: diabolical plot]
<sup>(Generated by SEDE: [/query/201360?ShowScore=0&Tag1=excel&Tag2=python&Tag3=NA&Tag4=NA#graph](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/201360?ShowScore=0&Tag1=excel&Tag2=python&Tag3=NA&Tag4=NA#graph))</sup>

Use the data explorer (SEDE) for that.

To do this with the API, is *possible* but not pretty.
For example, to replicate the above plot you would need to make 111<sup>(Age of SO in months)</sup> API calls for `python` like [**this call**](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/questions#fromdate=2016-08-01&todate=2016-08-08&order=desc&sort=creation&tagged=python&filter=!.UE8F0_CXHtXg77C&site=stackoverflow&run=true), a then make 111 API calls for `excel` with the same time parameters. (Then piece the results all together and plot it.)

Due to [rate limiting](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/throttle), those 222 calls would take *at least* 8 seconds.  More tags, or finer time slices, increases the time proportionally.

Also, you are allowed 10,000 API calls a day, max.  So that means, at most, 90 such runs per day -- including tests and development.

---

**UPDATE:**

For comparing compound tags, EG [excel]+[python] vs [excel]+[php], this would become even more problematic in the API.

But, I forked the SEDE query into [**something that compares tag set A versus tag set B**](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/767104/tag-set-a-versus-tag-set-b-growth-comparison?ShowScore=1&LeftTag1=excel&LeftTag2=python&RightTag1=excel&RightTag2=php#graph):

[image: plot 2]

Right now it does 1 by 1, 1 by 2, 2 by 1, and 2 by 2 tag combos. But it should be obvious how to extend it for more tags on each side.

Comment: wow.. yes this is very close to what I want. I have some follow up questions. How do I modify this query and where can I learn the various meaning of magical constants such as `posttypeid = 1`? Instead of comparing 1 tag against another, I prefer to compare a bunch of tags against another bunch of tags. E.g. excel-python against excel-php. I will modify my question such that I explicitly make clear, it may be a bunch of tags comparing.

Comment: How is your new question any different?  Merely change the parameters of the query I provided. Maybe add a sketch of what you you are looking for. ... For `PostTypeId`, etc., consult [the SEDE schema](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2677/database-schema-documentation-for-the-public-data-dump-and-sede).

Comment: Apologies. I realise I phrase my question poorly. I meant to say, compare  questions have both `excel` and `python` tags against questions that have both `excel` and `php` tags on them. I looked at your query and was thinking how to fork it. I realise I probably can only fork it to do pair-tags comparisons. Which is probably good enough for my own usage

Comment: See the updated answer.  I forked the query for tag-combo comparisons.